# How to write message to status line from handler class in Eclipse RCP programming

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I need to change status line message from a handler class. After reading the RCP tutorial and eclipse FAQ, I finally did something like this:

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().findView(AView.ID).getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager().setMessage( "Ha, I'm finished");
```

What a long invoking chain!

Am I doing it the right way? Thanks.

Comment: question: from where you call the handler (from AView?)? do you want to associate the message with AView?

Comment: No, I think AView is just a stub in this context, through which I can reach the StatusLineManager. (Kind of ugly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the threads](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg09776.html) [I see](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg79619.html) in the forums, that looks about right.

Beware though if you have asynchronous feedback to put in this status line.
See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg79691.html) for instance.

```
UIJob job = new UIJob() {
    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    //do the long running work here

    Runnable results = new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
              // update UI elements here;
             getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager().
               setMessage("End Pasting");
       }
    };
    display.asyncExec(results);
    }
};
job.schedule();
```

(Note: that may be not your case, but I add this code snippet just for information)